# how to convert yaml file data to a string in bash

Tags: bash, yaml, yq

How to convert YAML file data into string output, so that we can use it as a body parameter in the below curl request with the correct escape pattern.

curl request

```
curl -s  -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --location --request POST "${HOST}/api/v1/projects" --header "Authorization: Bearer "$token"" -d  '{"name":"'${PROJECT_NAME}'","openAPISpec":"none","isFileLoad": "true","openText": '${openText}',"source": "API"}'
```

```
---
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  description: 'This is a sample server Petstore server.  You can find out more about
    Swagger at [http://swagger.io](http://swagger.io) or on [irc.freenode.net, #swagger](http://swagger.io/irc/).  For
    this sample, you can use the api key `special-key` to test the authorization filters.'
  version: 1.0.6
  title: Swagger Petstore
  termsOfService: http://swagger.io/terms/
  contact:
    email: apiteam@swagger.io
  license:
    name: Apache 2.0
    url: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
host: petstore.swagger.io
basePath: "/v2"
tags:
- name: pet
  description: Everything about your Pets
  externalDocs:
    description: Find out more
    url: http://swagger.io
- name: store
  description: Access to Petstore orders
- name: user
  description: Operations about user
  externalDocs:
    description: Find out more about our store
    url: http://swagger.io
schemes:
- https
- http
paths:
  "/pet/{petId}/uploadImage":
    post:
      tags:
      - pet
      summary: uploads an image
      description: ''
      operationId: uploadFile
      consumes:
      - multipart/form-data
      produces:
      - application/json
      parameters:
      - name: petId
        in: path
        description: ID of pet to update
        required: true
        type: integer
        format: int64
      - name: additionalMetadata
        in: formData
        description: Additional data to pass to server
        required: false
        type: string
      - name: file
        in: formData
        description: file to upload
        required: false
        type: file
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          schema:
            "$ref": "#/definitions/ApiResponse"
      security:
      - petstore_auth:
        - write:pets
        - read:pets
  "/pet":
    post:
      tags:
      - pet
      summary: Add a new pet to the store
      description: ''
      operationId: addPet
      consumes:
      - application/json
      - application/xml
      produces:
      - application/json
      - application/xml
      parameters:
      - in: body
        name: body
        description: Pet object that needs to be added to the store
        required: true
        schema:
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Pet"
      responses:
        '405':
          description: Invalid input
      security:
      - petstore_auth:
        - write:pets
        - read:pets
    put:
      tags:
      - pet
      summary: Update an existing pet
      description: ''
      operationId: updatePet
      consumes:
      - application/json
      - application/xml
      produces:
      - application/json
      - application/xml
      parameters:
      - in: body
        name: body
        description: Pet object that needs to be added to the store
        required: true
        schema:
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Pet"
      responses:
        '400':
          description: Invalid ID supplied
        '404':
          description: Pet not found
        '405':
          description: Validation exception
      security:
      - petstore_auth:
        - write:pets
        - read:pets
  "/pet/findByStatus":
    get:
      tags:
      - pet
      summary: Finds Pets by status
      description: Multiple status values can be provided with comma separated strings
      operationId: findPetsByStatus
      produces:
      - application/json
      - application/xml
      parameters:
      - name: status
        in: query
        description: Status values that need to be considered for filter
        required: true
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
          enum:
          - available
          - pending
          - sold
          default: available
        collectionFormat: multi
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Pet"
        '400':
          description: Invalid status value
      security:
      - petstore_auth:
        - write:pets
        - read:pets
  "/pet/findByTags":
    get:
      tags:
      - pet
      summary: Finds Pets by tags
      description: Multiple tags can be provided with comma separated strings. Use
        tag1, tag2, tag3 for testing.
      operationId: findPetsByTags
      produces:
      - application/json
      - application/xml
      parameters:
      - name: tags
        in: query
        description: Tags to filter by
        required: true
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
        collectionFormat: multi
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Pet"
        '400':
          description: Invalid tag value
      security:
      - petstore_auth:
        - write:pets
        - read:pets
      deprecated: true
  "/pet/{petId}":
    get:
      tags:
      - pet
      summary: Find pet by ID
      description: Returns a single pet
      operationId: getPetById
      produces:
      - application/json
      - application/xml
      parameters:
      - name: petId
        in: path
        description: ID of pet to return
        required: true
        type: integer
        format: int64
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          schema:
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Pet"
        '400':
          description: Invalid ID supplied
        '404':
          description: Pet not found
      security:
      - api_key: []
    post:
      tags:
      - pet
      summary: Updates a pet in the store with form data
      description: ''
      operationId: updatePetWithForm
      consumes:
      - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
      produces:
      - application/json
      - application/xml
      parameters:
      - name: petId
        in: path
        description: ID of pet that needs to be updated
        required: true
        type: integer
        format: int64
      - name: name
        in: formData
        description: Updated name of the pet
        required: false
        type: string
      - name: status
        in: formData
        description: Updated status of the pet
        required: false
        type: string
      responses:
        '405':
          description: Invalid input
      security:
      - petstore_auth:
        - write:pets
        - read:pets
    delete:
      tags:
      - pet
      summary: Deletes a pet
      description: ''
      operationId: deletePet
      produces:
      - application/json
      - application/xml
      parameters:
      - name: api_key
        in: header
        required: false
        type: string
      - name: petId
        in: path
        description: Pet id to delete
        required: true
        type: integer
        format: int64
      responses:
        '400':
          description: Invalid ID supplied
        '404':
          description: Pet not found
      security:
      - petstore_auth:
        - write:pets
        - read:pets
  "/store/order":
    post:
      tags:
      - store
      summary: Place an order for a pet
      description: ''
      operationId: placeOrder
      consumes:
      - application/json
      produces:
      - application/json
      - application/xml
      parameters:
      - in: body
        name: body
        description: order placed for purchasing the pet
        required: true
        schema:
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Order"
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          schema:
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Order"
        '400':
          description: Invalid Order
  "/store/order/{orderId}":
    get:
      tags:
      - store
      summary: Find purchase order by ID
      description: For valid response try integer IDs with value >= 1 and <= 10. Other
        values will generated exceptions
      operationId: getOrderById
      produces:
      - application/json
      - application/xml
      parameters:
      - name: orderId
        in: path
        description: ID of pet that needs to be fetched
        required: true
        type: integer
        maximum: 10
        minimum: 1
        format: int64
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          schema:
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Order"
        '400':
          description: Invalid ID supplied
        '404':
          description: Order not found
    delete:
      tags:
      - store
      summary: Delete purchase order by ID
      description: For valid response try integer IDs with positive integer value.
        Negative or non-integer values will generate API errors
      operationId: deleteOrder
      produces:
      - application/json
      - application/xml
      parameters:
      - name: orderId
        in: path
        description: ID of the order that needs to be deleted
        required: true
        type: integer
        minimum: 1
        format: int64
      responses:
        '400':
          description: Invalid ID supplied
        '404':
          description: Order not found
  "/store/inventory":
    get:
      tags:
      - store
      summary: Returns pet inventories by status
      description: Returns a map of status codes to quantities
      operationId: getInventory
      produces:
      - application/json
      parameters: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          schema:
            type: object
            additionalProperties:
              type: integer
              format: int32
      security:
      - api_key: []
  "/user/createWithArray":
    post:
      tags:
      - user
      summary: Creates list of users with given input array
      description: ''
      operationId: createUsersWithArrayInput
      consumes:
      - application/json
      produces:
      - application/json
      - application/xml
      parameters:
      - in: body
        name: body
        description: List of user object
        required: true
        schema:
          type: array
          items:
            "$ref": "#/definitions/User"
      responses:
        default:
          description: successful operation
  "/user/createWithList":
    post:
      tags:
      - user
      summary: Creates list of users with given input array
      description: ''
      operationId: createUsersWithListInput
      consumes:
      - application/json
      produces:
      - application/json
      - application/xml
      parameters:
      - in: body
        name: body
        description: List of user object
        required: true
        schema:
          type: array
          items:
            "$ref": "#/definitions/User"
      responses:
        default:
          description: successful operation
  "/user/{username}":
    get:
      tags:
      - user
      summary: Get user by user name
      description: ''
      operationId: getUserByName
      produces:
      - application/json
      - application/xml
      parameters:
      - name: username
        in: path
        description: 'The name that needs to be fetched. Use user1 for testing. '
        required: true
        type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          schema:
            "$ref": "#/definitions/User"
        '400':
          description: Invalid username supplied
        '404':
          description: User not found
    put:
      tags:
      - user
      summary: Updated user
      description: This can only be done by the logged in user.
      operationId: updateUser
      consumes:
      - application/json
      produces:
      - application/json
      - application/xml
      parameters:
      - name: username
        in: path
        description: name that need to be updated
        required: true
        type: string
      - in: body
        name: body
        description: Updated user object
        required: true
        schema:
          "$ref": "#/definitions/User"
      responses:
        '400':
          description: Invalid user supplied
        '404':
          description: User not found
    delete:
      tags:
      - user
      summary: Delete user
      description: This can only be done by the logged in user.
      operationId: deleteUser
      produces:
      - application/json
      - application/xml
      parameters:
      - name: username
        in: path
        description: The name that needs to be deleted
        required: true
        type: string
      responses:
        '400':
          description: Invalid username supplied
        '404':
          description: User not found
  "/user/login":
    get:
      tags:
      - user
      summary: Logs user into the system
      description: ''
      operationId: loginUser
      produces:
      - application/json
      - application/xml
      parameters:
      - name: username
        in: query
        description: The user name for login
        required: true
        type: string
      - name: password
        in: query
        description: The password for login in clear text
        required: true
        type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          headers:
            X-Expires-After:
              type: string
              format: date-time
              description: date in UTC when token expires
            X-Rate-Limit:
              type: integer
              format: int32
              description: calls per hour allowed by the user
          schema:
            type: string
        '400':
          description: Invalid username/password supplied
  "/user/logout":
    get:
      tags:
      - user
      summary: Logs out current logged in user session
      description: ''
      operationId: logoutUser
      produces:
      - application/json
      - application/xml
      parameters: []
      responses:
        default:
          description: successful operation
  "/user":
    post:
      tags:
      - user
      summary: Create user
      description: This can only be done by the logged in user.
      operationId: createUser
      consumes:
      - application/json
      produces:
      - application/json
      - application/xml
      parameters:
      - in: body
        name: body
        description: Created user object
        required: true
        schema:
          "$ref": "#/definitions/User"
      responses:
        default:
          description: successful operation
securityDefinitions:
  api_key:
    type: apiKey
    name: api_key
    in: header
  petstore_auth:
    type: oauth2
    authorizationUrl: https://petstore.swagger.io/oauth/authorize
    flow: implicit
    scopes:
      read:pets: read your pets
      write:pets: modify pets in your account
definitions:
  ApiResponse:
    type: object
    properties:
      code:
        type: integer
        format: int32
      type:
        type: string
      message:
        type: string
  Category:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        format: int64
      name:
        type: string
    xml:
      name: Category
  Pet:
    type: object
    required:
    - name
    - photoUrls
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        format: int64
      category:
        "$ref": "#/definitions/Category"
      name:
        type: string
        example: doggie
      photoUrls:
        type: array
        xml:
          wrapped: true
        items:
          type: string
          xml:
            name: photoUrl
      tags:
        type: array
        xml:
          wrapped: true
        items:
          xml:
            name: tag
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Tag"
      status:
        type: string
        description: pet status in the store
        enum:
        - available
        - pending
        - sold
    xml:
      name: Pet
  Tag:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        format: int64
      name:
        type: string
    xml:
      name: Tag
  Order:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        format: int64
      petId:
        type: integer
        format: int64
      quantity:
        type: integer
        format: int32
      shipDate:
        type: string
        format: date-time
      status:
        type: string
        description: Order Status
        enum:
        - placed
        - approved
        - delivered
      complete:
        type: boolean
    xml:
      name: Order
  User:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        format: int64
      username:
        type: string
      firstName:
        type: string
      lastName:
        type: string
      email:
        type: string
      password:
        type: string
      phone:
        type: string
      userStatus:
        type: integer
        format: int32
        description: User Status
    xml:
      name: User
externalDocs:
  description: Find out more about Swagger
  url: http://swagger.io
```

Below is the successful string output I got from the request payload when I use 'Inspect' from the google browser.

So when we convert the YAML file data to string from the Linux bash and use it in the curl request mentioned above for '${openText}' field we are expected to have the string like the one below the string output.

I tried to yq tool but don't know to use it or whether it will give the exact result.

Expected/Close-To-Expected is string output.

```
"---\nswagger: '2.0'\ninfo:\n  description: 'This is a sample server Petstore server.  You can find out more about\n    Swagger at [http://swagger.io](http://swagger.io) or on [irc.freenode.net, #swagger](http://swagger.io/irc/).  For\n    this sample, you can use the api key `special-key` to test the authorization filters.'\n  version: 1.0.6\n  title: Swagger Petstore\n  termsOfService: http://swagger.io/terms/\n  contact:\n    email: apiteam@swagger.io\n  license:\n    name: Apache 2.0\n    url: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html\nhost: petstore.swagger.io\nbasePath: \"/v2\"\ntags:\n- name: pet\n  description: Everything about your Pets\n  externalDocs:\n    description: Find out more\n    url: http://swagger.io\n- name: store\n  description: Access to Petstore orders\n- name: user\n  description: Operations about user\n  externalDocs:\n    description: Find out more about our store\n    url: http://swagger.io\nschemes:\n- https\n- http\npaths:\n  \"/pet/{petId}/uploadImage\":\n    post:\n      tags:\n      - pet\n      summary: uploads an image\n      description: ''\n      operationId: uploadFile\n      consumes:\n      - multipart/form-data\n      produces:\n      - application/json\n      parameters:\n      - name: petId\n        in: path\n        description: ID of pet to update\n        required: true\n        type: integer\n        format: int64\n      - name: additionalMetadata\n        in: formData\n        description: Additional data to pass to server\n        required: false\n        type: string\n      - name: file\n        in: formData\n        description: file to upload\n        required: false\n        type: file\n      responses:\n        '200':\n          description: successful operation\n          schema:\n            \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/ApiResponse\"\n      security:\n      - petstore_auth:\n        - write:pets\n        - read:pets\n  \"/pet\":\n    post:\n      tags:\n      - pet\n      summary: Add a new pet to the store\n      description: ''\n      operationId: addPet\n      consumes:\n      - application/json\n      - application/xml\n      produces:\n      - application/json\n      - application/xml\n      parameters:\n      - in: body\n        name: body\n        description: Pet object that needs to be added to the store\n        required: true\n        schema:\n          \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/Pet\"\n      responses:\n        '405':\n          description: Invalid input\n      security:\n      - petstore_auth:\n        - write:pets\n        - read:pets\n    put:\n      tags:\n      - pet\n      summary: Update an existing pet\n      description: ''\n      operationId: updatePet\n      consumes:\n      - application/json\n      - application/xml\n      produces:\n      - application/json\n      - application/xml\n      parameters:\n      - in: body\n        name: body\n        description: Pet object that needs to be added to the store\n        required: true\n        schema:\n          \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/Pet\"\n      responses:\n        '400':\n          description: Invalid ID supplied\n        '404':\n          description: Pet not found\n        '405':\n          description: Validation exception\n      security:\n      - petstore_auth:\n        - write:pets\n        - read:pets\n  \"/pet/findByStatus\":\n    get:\n      tags:\n      - pet\n      summary: Finds Pets by status\n      description: Multiple status values can be provided with comma separated strings\n      operationId: findPetsByStatus\n      produces:\n      - application/json\n      - application/xml\n      parameters:\n      - name: status\n        in: query\n        description: Status values that need to be considered for filter\n        required: true\n        type: array\n        items:\n          type: string\n          enum:\n          - available\n          - pending\n          - sold\n          default: available\n        collectionFormat: multi\n      responses:\n        '200':\n          description: successful operation\n          schema:\n            type: array\n            items:\n              \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/Pet\"\n        '400':\n          description: Invalid status value\n      security:\n      - petstore_auth:\n        - write:pets\n        - read:pets\n  \"/pet/findByTags\":\n    get:\n      tags:\n      - pet\n      summary: Finds Pets by tags\n      description: Multiple tags can be provided with comma separated strings. Use\n        tag1, tag2, tag3 for testing.\n      operationId: findPetsByTags\n      produces:\n      - application/json\n      - application/xml\n      parameters:\n      - name: tags\n        in: query\n        description: Tags to filter by\n        required: true\n        type: array\n        items:\n          type: string\n        collectionFormat: multi\n      responses:\n        '200':\n          description: successful operation\n          schema:\n            type: array\n            items:\n              \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/Pet\"\n        '400':\n          description: Invalid tag value\n      security:\n      - petstore_auth:\n        - write:pets\n        - read:pets\n      deprecated: true\n  \"/pet/{petId}\":\n    get:\n      tags:\n      - pet\n      summary: Find pet by ID\n      description: Returns a single pet\n      operationId: getPetById\n      produces:\n      - application/json\n      - application/xml\n      parameters:\n      - name: petId\n        in: path\n        description: ID of pet to return\n        required: true\n        type: integer\n        format: int64\n      responses:\n        '200':\n          description: successful operation\n          schema:\n            \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/Pet\"\n        '400':\n          description: Invalid ID supplied\n        '404':\n          description: Pet not found\n      security:\n      - api_key: []\n    post:\n      tags:\n      - pet\n      summary: Updates a pet in the store with form data\n      description: ''\n      operationId: updatePetWithForm\n      consumes:\n      - application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n      produces:\n      - application/json\n      - application/xml\n      parameters:\n      - name: petId\n        in: path\n        description: ID of pet that needs to be updated\n        required: true\n        type: integer\n        format: int64\n      - name: name\n        in: formData\n        description: Updated name of the pet\n        required: false\n        type: string\n      - name: status\n        in: formData\n        description: Updated status of the pet\n        required: false\n        type: string\n      responses:\n        '405':\n          description: Invalid input\n      security:\n      - petstore_auth:\n        - write:pets\n        - read:pets\n    delete:\n      tags:\n      - pet\n      summary: Deletes a pet\n      description: ''\n      operationId: deletePet\n      produces:\n      - application/json\n      - application/xml\n      parameters:\n      - name: api_key\n        in: header\n        required: false\n        type: string\n      - name: petId\n        in: path\n        description: Pet id to delete\n        required: true\n        type: integer\n        format: int64\n      responses:\n        '400':\n          description: Invalid ID supplied\n        '404':\n          description: Pet not found\n      security:\n      - petstore_auth:\n        - write:pets\n        - read:pets\n  \"/store/order\":\n    post:\n      tags:\n      - store\n      summary: Place an order for a pet\n      description: ''\n      operationId: placeOrder\n      consumes:\n      - application/json\n      produces:\n      - application/json\n      - application/xml\n      parameters:\n      - in: body\n        name: body\n        description: order placed for purchasing the pet\n        required: true\n        schema:\n          \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/Order\"\n      responses:\n        '200':\n          description: successful operation\n          schema:\n            \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/Order\"\n        '400':\n          description: Invalid Order\n  \"/store/order/{orderId}\":\n    get:\n      tags:\n      - store\n      summary: Find purchase order by ID\n      description: For valid response try integer IDs with value >= 1 and <= 10. Other\n        values will generated exceptions\n      operationId: getOrderById\n      produces:\n      - application/json\n      - application/xml\n      parameters:\n      - name: orderId\n        in: path\n        description: ID of pet that needs to be fetched\n        required: true\n        type: integer\n        maximum: 10\n        minimum: 1\n        format: int64\n      responses:\n        '200':\n          description: successful operation\n          schema:\n            \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/Order\"\n        '400':\n          description: Invalid ID supplied\n        '404':\n          description: Order not found\n    delete:\n      tags:\n      - store\n      summary: Delete purchase order by ID\n      description: For valid response try integer IDs with positive integer value.\n        Negative or non-integer values will generate API errors\n      operationId: deleteOrder\n      produces:\n      - application/json\n      - application/xml\n      parameters:\n      - name: orderId\n        in: path\n        description: ID of the order that needs to be deleted\n        required: true\n        type: integer\n        minimum: 1\n        format: int64\n      responses:\n        '400':\n          description: Invalid ID supplied\n        '404':\n          description: Order not found\n  \"/store/inventory\":\n    get:\n      tags:\n      - store\n      summary: Returns pet inventories by status\n      description: Returns a map of status codes to quantities\n      operationId: getInventory\n      produces:\n      - application/json\n      parameters: []\n      responses:\n        '200':\n          description: successful operation\n          schema:\n            type: object\n            additionalProperties:\n              type: integer\n              format: int32\n      security:\n      - api_key: []\n  \"/user/createWithArray\":\n    post:\n      tags:\n      - user\n      summary: Creates list of users with given input array\n      description: ''\n      operationId: createUsersWithArrayInput\n      consumes:\n      - application/json\n      produces:\n      - application/json\n      - application/xml\n      parameters:\n      - in: body\n         found\n    put:\n      tags:\n      - user\n      summary: Updated user\n          \n      password:\n        type: string\n      phone:\n        type: string\n      userStatus:\n        type: integer\n        format: int32\n        description: User Status\n    xml:\n      name: User\nexternalDocs:\n  description: Find out more about Swagger\n  url: http://swagger.io\n\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `JSON` as the `curl` input, but you have `YAML`. So:

```
yq -p yaml -o json file.yaml |                   # convert YAML to JSON
curl -s -H "Accept: application/json" \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   --location \
   --request POST "${HOST}/api/v1/projects" \
   --header "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
   -d "@/dev/stdin" https://<URL>
```

If you need to modify the `YAML` file, you can process it before with the `yq` command

Comment: Have you tried this solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The curl request header specifies it accepts 'application/json' but you're not passing in JSON.

To convert a yaml to a JSON string, instead of using sed do:

```bash
openText=$(yq -oj petstore.yaml)
```

Disclaimer: I wrote yq

Answer (score -1):

I tried the below code.

```
openText=$(sed -z 's/\n/\\n/g' petstore.yaml | tr -d ' ')

curl -s  -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --location --request POST "${HOST}/api/v1/projects" --header "Authorization: Bearer "$token"" -d  '{"name":"'${PROJECT_NAME}'","openAPISpec":"none","isFileLoad": "true","openText": '${openText}',"source": "API"}'
```

String output seems to be ok with ( sed -z 's/\n/\n/g' petstore.yaml | tr -d ' ')

```
---\nswagger:'2.0'\ninfo:\ndescription:'ThisisasampleserverPetstoreserver.Youcanfindoutmoreabout\nSwaggerat[http://swagger.io](http://swagger.io)oron[irc.freenode.net,#swagger](http://swagger.io/irc/).For\nthissample,youcanusetheapikey`special-key`totesttheauthorizationfilters.'\nversion:1.0.6\ntitle:SwaggerPetstore\ntermsOfService:http://swagger.io/terms/\ncontact:\nemail:apiteam@swagger.io\nlicense:\nname:Apache2.0\nurl:http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html\nhost:petstore.swagger.io\nbasePath:"/v2"\ntags:\n-name:pet\ndescription:EverythingaboutyourPets\nexternalDocs:\ndescription:Findoutmore\nurl:http://swagger.io\n-name:store\ndescription:AccesstoPetstoreorders\n-name:user\ndescription:Operationsaboutuser\nexternalDocs:\ndescription:Findoutmoreaboutourstore\nurl:http://swagger.io\nschemes:\n-https\n-http\npaths:\n"/pet/{petId}/uploadImage":\npost:\ntags:\n-pet\nsummary:uploadsanimage\ndescription:''\noperationId:uploadFile\nconsumes:\n-multipart/form-data\nproduces:\n-application/json\nparameters:\n-name:petId\nin:path\ndescription:IDofpettoupdate\nrequired:true\ntype:integer\nformat:int64\n-name:additionalMetadata\nin:formData\ndescription:Additionaldatatopasstoserver\nrequired:false\ntype:string\n-name:file\nin:formData\ndescription:filetoupload\nrequired:false\ntype:file\nresponses:\n'200':\ndescription:successfuloperation\nschema:\n"$ref":"#/definitions/ApiResponse"\nsecurity:\n-petstore_auth:\n-write:pets\n-read:pets\n"/pet":\npost:\ntags:\n-pet\nsummary:Addanewpettothestore\ndescription:''\noperationId:addPet\nconsumes:\n-application/json\n-application/xml\nproduces:\n-application/json\n-application/xml\nparameters:\n-in:body\nname:body\ndescription:Petobjectthatneedstobeaddedtothestore\nrequired:true\nschema:\n"$ref":"#/definitions/Pet"\nresponses:\n'405':\ndescription:Invalidinput\nsecurity:\n-petstore_auth:\n-write:pets\n-read:pets\nput:\ntags:\n-pet\nsummary:Updateanexistingpet\ndescription:''\noperationId:updatePet\nconsumes:\n-application/json\n-application/xml\nproduces:\n-application/json\n-application/xml\nparameters:\n-in:body\nname:body\ndescription:Petobjectthatneedstobeaddedtothestore\nrequired:true\nschema:\n"$ref":"#/definitions/Pet"\nresponses:\n'400':\ndescription:InvalidIDsupplied\n'404':\ndescription:Petnotfound\n'405':\ndescription:Validationexception\nsecurity:\n-petstore_auth:\n-write:pets\n-read:pets\n"/pet/findByStatus":\nget:\ntags:\n-pet\nsummary:FindsPetsbystatus\ndescription:Multiplestatusvaluescanbeprovidedwithcommaseparatedstrings\noperationId:findPetsByStatus\nproduces:\n-application/json\n-application/xml\nparameters:\n-name:status\nin:query\ndescription:Statusvaluesthatneedtobeconsideredforfilter\nrequired:true\ntype:array\nitems:\ntype:string\nenum:\n-available\n-pending\n-sold\ndefault:available\ncollectionFormat:multi\nresponses:\n'200':\ndescription:successfuloperation\nschema:\ntype:array\nitems:\n"$ref":"#/definitions/Pet"\n'400':\ndescription:Invalidstatusvalue\nsecurity:\n-petstore_auth:\n-write:pets\n-read:pets\n"/pet/findByTags":\nget:\ntags:\n-pet\nsummary:FindsPetsbytags\ndescription:Multipletagscanbeprovidedwithcommaseparatedstrings.Use\ntag1,tag2,tag3fortesting.\noperationId:findPetsByTags\nproduces:\n-application/json\n-application/xml\nparameters:\n-name:tags\nin:query\ndescription:Tagstofilterby\nrequired:true\ntype:array\nitems:\ntype:string\ncollectionFormat:multi\nresponses:\n'200':\ndescription:successfuloperation\nschema:\ntype:array\nitems:\n"$ref":"#/definitions/Pet"\n'400':\ndescription:Invalidtagvalue\nsecurity:\n-petstore_auth:\n-write:pets\n-read:pets\ndeprecated:true\n"/pet/{petId}":\nget:\ntags:\n-pet\nsummary:FindpetbyID\ndescription:Returnsasinglepet\noperationId:getPetById\nproduces:\n-application/json\n-application/xml\nparameters:\n-name:petId\nin:path\ndescription:IDofpettoreturn\nrequired:true\ntype:integer\nformat:int64\nresponses:\n'200':\ndescription:successfuloperation\nschema:\n"$ref":"#/definitions/Pet"\n'400':\ndescription:InvalidIDsupplied\n'404':\ndescription:Petnotfound\nsecurity:\n-api_key:[]\npost:\ntags:\n-pet\nsummary:Updatesapetinthestorewithformdata\ndescription:''\noperationId:updatePetWithForm\nconsumes:\n-application/x-www-form-urlencoded\nproduces:\n-application/json\n-application/xml\nparameters:\n-name:petId\nin:path\ndescription:IDofpetthatneedstobeupdated\nrequired:true\ntype:integer\nformat:int64\n-name:name\nin:formData\ndescription:Updatednameofthepet\nrequired:false\ntype:string\n-name:status\nin:formData\ndescription:Updatedstatusofthepet\nrequired:false\ntype:string\nresponses:\n'405':\ndescription:Invalidinput\nsecurity:\n-petstore_auth:\n-write:pets\n-read:pets\ndelete:\ntags:\n-pet\nsummary:Deletesapet\ndescription:''\noperationId:deletePet\nproduces:\n-application/json\n-application/xml\nparameters:\n-name:api_key\nin:header\nrequired:false\ntype:string\n-name:petId\nin:path\ndescription:Petidtodelete\nrequired:true\ntype:integer\nformat:int64\nresponses:\n'400':\ndescription:InvalidIDsupplied\n'404':\ndescription:Petnotfound\nsecurity:\n-petstore_auth:\n-write:pets\n-read:pets\n"/store/order":\npost:\ntags:\n-store\nsummary:Placeanorderforapet\ndescription:''\noperationId:placeOrder\nconsumes:\n-application/json\nproduces:\n-application/json\n-application/xml\nparameters:\n-in:body\nname:body\ndescription:orderplacedforpurchasingthepet\nrequired:true\nschema:\n"$ref":"#/definitions/Order"\nresponses:\n'200':\ndescription:successfuloperation\nschema:\n"$ref":"#/definitions/Order"\n'400':\ndescription:InvalidOrder\n"/store/order/{orderId}":\nget:\ntags:\n-store\nsummary:FindpurchaseorderbyID\ndescription:ForvalidresponsetryintegerIDswithvalue>=1and<=10.Other\nvalueswillgeneratedexceptions\noperationId:getOrderById\nproduces:\n-application/json\n-application/xml\nparameters:\n-name:orderId\nin:path\ndescription:IDofpetthatneedstobefetched\nrequired:true\ntype:integer\nmaximum:10\nminimum:1\nformat:int64\nresponses:\n'200':\ndescription:successfuloperation\nschema:\n"$ref":"#/definitions/Order"\n'400':\ndescription:InvalidIDsupplied\n'404':\ndescription:Ordernotfound\ndelete:\ntags:\n-store\nsummary:DeletepurchaseorderbyID\ndescription:ForvalidresponsetryintegerIDswithpositiveintegervalue.\nNegativeornon-integervalueswillgenerateAPIerrors\noperationId:deleteOrder\nproduces:\n-application/json\n-application/xml\nparameters:\n-name:orderId\nin:path\ndescription:IDoftheorderthatneedstobedeleted\nrequired:true\ntype:integer\nminimum:1\nformat:int64\nresponses:\n'400':\ndescription:InvalidIDsupplied\n'404':\ndescription:Ordernotfound\n"/store/inventory":\nget:\ntags:\n-store\nsummary:Returnspetinventoriesbystatus\ndescription:Returnsamapofstatuscodestoquantities\noperationId:getInventory\nproduces:\n-application/json\nparameters:[]\nresponses:\n'200':\ndescription:successfuloperation\nschema:\ntype:object\nadditionalProperties:\ntype:integer\nformat:int32\nsecurity:\n-api_key:[]\n"/user/createWithArray":\npost:\ntags:\n-user\nsummary:Createslistofuserswithgiveninputarray\ndescription:''\noperationId:createUsersWithArrayInput\nconsumes:\n-application/json\nproduces:\n-application/json\n-application/xml\nparameters:\n-in:body\nname:body\ndescription:Listofuserobject\nrequired:true\nschema:\ntype:array\nitems:\n"$ref":"#/definitions/User"\nresponses:\ndefault:\ndescription:successfuloperation\n"/user/createWithList":\npost:\ntags:\n-user\nsummary:Createslistofuserswithgiveninputarray\ndescription:''\noperationId:createUsersWithListInput\nconsumes:\n-application/json\nproduces:\n-application/json\n-application/xml\nparameters:\n-in:body\nname:body\ndescription:Listofuserobject\nrequired:true\nschema:\ntype:array\nitems:\n"$ref":"#/definitions/User"\nresponses:\ndefault:\ndescription:successfuloperation\n"/user/{username}":\nget:\ntags:\n-user\nsummary:Getuserbyusername\ndescription:''\noperationId:getUserByName\nproduces:\n-application/json\n-application/xml\nparameters:\n-name:username\nin:path\ndescription:'Thenamethatneedstobefetched.Useuser1fortesting.'\nrequired:true\ntype:string\nresponses:\n'200':\ndescription:successfuloperation\nschema:\n"$ref":"#/definitions/User"\n'400':\ndescription:Invalidusernamesupplied\n'404':\ndescription:Usernotfound\nput:\ntags:\n-user\nsummary:Updateduser\ndescription:Thiscanonlybedonebytheloggedinuser.\noperationId:updateUser\nconsumes:\n-application/json\nproduces:\n-application/json\n-application/xml\nparameters:\n-name:username\nin:path\ndescription:namethatneedtobeupdated\nrequired:true\ntype:string\n-in:body\nname:body\ndescription:Updateduserobject\nrequired:true\nschema:\n"$ref":"#/definitions/User"\nresponses:\n'400':\ndescription:Invalidusersupplied\n'404':\ndescription:Usernotfound\ndelete:\ntags:\n-user\nsummary:Deleteuser\ndescription:Thiscanonlybedonebytheloggedinuser.\noperationId:deleteUser\nproduces:\n-application/json\n-application/xml\nparameters:\n-name:username\nin:path\ndescription:Thenamethatneedstobedeleted\nrequired:true\ntype:string\nresponses:\n'400':\ndescription:Invalidusernamesupplied\n'404':\ndescription:Usernotfound\n"/user/login":\nget:\ntags:\n-user\nsummary:Logsuserintothesystem\ndescription:''\noperationId:loginUser\nproduces:\n-application/json\n-application/xml\nparameters:\n-name:username\nin:query\ndescription:Theusernameforlogin\nrequired:true\ntype:string\n-name:password\nin:query\ndescription:Thepasswordforloginincleartext\nrequired:true\ntype:string\nresponses:\n'200':\ndescription:successfuloperation\nheaders:\nX-Expires-After:\ntype:string\nformat:date-time\ndescription:dateinUTCwhentokenexpires\nX-Rate-Limit:\ntype:integer\nformat:int32\ndescription:callsperhourallowedbytheuser\nschema:\ntype:string\n'400':\ndescription:Invalidusername/passwordsupplied\n"/user/logout":\nget:\ntags:\n-user\nsummary:Logsoutcurrentloggedinusersession\ndescription:''\noperationId:logoutUser\nproduces:\n-application/json\n-application/xml\nparameters:[]\nresponses:\ndefault:\ndescription:successfuloperation\n"/user":\npost:\ntags:\n-user\nsummary:Createuser\ndescription:Thiscanonlybedonebytheloggedinuser.\noperationId:createUser\nconsumes:\n-application/json\nproduces:\n-application/json\n-application/xml\nparameters:\n-in:body\nname:body\ndescription:Createduserobject\nrequired:true\nschema:\n"$ref":"#/definitions/User"\nresponses:\ndefault:\ndescription:successfuloperation\nsecurityDefinitions:\napi_key:\ntype:apiKey\nname:api_key\nin:header\npetstore_auth:\ntype:oauth2\nauthorizationUrl:https://petstore.swagger.io/oauth/authorize\nflow:implicit\nscopes:\nread:pets:readyourpets\nwrite:pets:modifypetsinyouraccount\ndefinitions:\nApiResponse:\ntype:object\nproperties:\ncode:\ntype:integer\nformat:int32\ntype:\ntype:string\nmessage:\ntype:string\nCategory:\ntype:object\nproperties:\nid:\ntype:integer\nformat:int64\nname:\ntype:string\nxml:\nname:Category\nPet:\ntype:object\nrequired:\n-name\n-photoUrls\nproperties:\nid:\ntype:integer\nformat:int64\ncategory:\n"$ref":"#/definitions/Category"\nname:\ntype:string\nexample:doggie\nphotoUrls:\ntype:array\nxml:\nwrapped:true\nitems:\ntype:string\nxml:\nname:photoUrl\ntags:\ntype:array\nxml:\nwrapped:true\nitems:\nxml:\nname:tag\n"$ref":"#/definitions/Tag"\nstatus:\ntype:string\ndescription:petstatusinthestore\nenum:\n-available\n-pending\n-sold\nxml:\nname:Pet\nTag:\ntype:object\nproperties:\nid:\ntype:integer\nformat:int64\nname:\ntype:string\nxml:\nname:Tag\nOrder:\ntype:object\nproperties:\nid:\ntype:integer\nformat:int64\npetId:\ntype:integer\nformat:int64\nquantity:\ntype:integer\nformat:int32\nshipDate:\ntype:string\nformat:date-time\nstatus:\ntype:string\ndescription:OrderStatus\nenum:\n-placed\n-approved\n-delivered\ncomplete:\ntype:boolean\nxml:\nname:Order\nUser:\ntype:object\nproperties:\nid:\ntype:integer\nformat:int64\nusername:\ntype:string\nfirstName:\ntype:string\nlastName:\ntype:string\nemail:\ntype:string\npassword:\ntype:string\nphone:\ntype:string\nuserStatus:\ntype:integer\nformat:int32\ndescription:UserStatus\nxml:\nname:User\nexternalDocs:\ndescription:FindoutmoreaboutSwagger\nurl:http://swagger.io\n\n
```

But java app throws below error.

```
{"timestamp":"2022-12-08T20:47:59.420+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 111]","path":"/api/v1/projects"}
```

The conversion is working. But needs to be put it in the right format/structure to pass it through the java app.
Will work on it and post here upon success.

Comment: This should be an edit to your initial question